# 14.04 Cannot remove lenses

Tags: 14.04, uninstall, lenses

I want to remove photo, video and music lenses from the dash, in 12.04 was enough to purge the unity-lens-whatever but in 14.04 this trick doesn't do the job, neither remove the scopes.

Ideas?

---

Found a solution, using dconf I edited com/canonical/unity/dash and removed the unwanted entries.

Will this method cause any issues or conflicts in the future?

Comment: Have you tried `sudo apt-get remove unity-lens-photos`... ?

Comment: You could also try the following: Go to the applications lens, you will see all dash plugins. Click on the dash you want to disable, click on deactivate.

Comment: did tried that already but doesn't work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can indeed remove the unwanted lenses (like you already mentioned) using `dconf`. You can do that by using either the `dconf editor` (from the repositories) or by running

```
gsettings get com.canonical.Unity.Dash scopes
```

Then remove the ones you don't want from the list that appears, and set the changed list like:

```
gsettings set com.canonical.Unity.Dash scopes "['home.scope', 'applications.scope', 'files.scope', 'video.scope', 'music.scope']"
```

In case you might have unwanted side efects, or you want to return to original settings, simply add the removed items similarly, or run in a terminal:

```
gsettings reset com.canonical.Unity.Dash scopes
```

The GUI way would be to open `dconf editor` and go to `com > canonical > unity > dash` and press the `back to default` button (right/bottom):

[image]